# Totals homework

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I have this question for homework:

> $$\begin{align} A &= \lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\rbrace \\ B &=\lbrace 1, 2, 6, 8\rbrace\end{align}$$ Calculate $A-B$.

Answer $A-B = \lbrace 3, 4, 5, 7, 9\rbrace$.

I think it is correct but I am not sure.

Comment: It is correct.  Have confidence.

Comment: Is correct. $A \setminus B$ (or $A-B$) consists of all those elements in $A$ that are not in $B$.

Comment: What else could it be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed correct. It's the set minus operation, also written as ${A\setminus B}$